# Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, data-science

i have code like this to make predict with xgboost

```
akhir_test['Akhir_Prediction'] = reg.predict(X_test)
akhir_all = pd.concat([akhir_test, akhir_train], sort=False)
```

but i got error in length, but when i check akhir_test and akhir_train have same shape.

[shape of akhir_test, ect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1W3S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your Shape can be diffrent or content can be different have you ever tried to ignore_index param in concat

```
akhir_all  = pd.concat([akhir_test,akhir_train], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

this will fill NaN for not matched index. So you can see also what would be problem to get this error

Comment: thanks, now i get error like this
ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['hour', 'dayofweek', 'quarter', 'month', 'year', 'dayofyear', 'dayofmonth', 'weekofyear'] ['f0']
expected dayofweek, weekofyear, dayofmonth, year, quarter, month, dayofyear, hour in input data
training data did not have the following fields: f0

Comment: http://aidangawronski.com/dealing-with-the-valueerror-feature_names-mismatch-using-xgboost-in-python/

Better Look here if you start now